# How detect NFC payment on app?

Tags: android, nfc, payment, android-pay

Is it possible to detect when an Android, with payment app on it, is used to make a payment by tapping the NFC reader?  (For example, going on a bus or train.)

Can you register or detect in some way such NFC events/payments on the phone (ie, payments processed by some other app on the phone)?

Comment: FYI this question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302410/failed-an-audit-for-flagging-a-question-asking-for-links-to-example-code)

Comment: thats great! Thank you !